# Twitter OAuth Process going in circles? How to obtain unauthorized request token?

Tags: twitter, oauth

I am trying to implement a twitter login/authorization in order to access the api for a specific user going by the guide that twitter provides [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter). I am getting confused at the first step where I am supposed to obtain an unsigned request token from twitter via the api endpoint `/oauth/request_token`. According to the OAuth Specifications I am supposed to send a signature with this request, but according to [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature) description of how to generate a signature I need to include an oauth_token which is exactly what I am supposed to get from `/oauth/request_token/`. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

When you request an unauthorized request token, as you state you obviously cannot include the `oauth_token` parameter because you do not have one yet. You can see from the Twitter documentation for obtaining a request token that the request only includes the following parameters:

```
oauth_callback
oauth_consumer_key
oauth_nonce
oauth_signature
oauth_signature_method
oauth_timestamp
oauth_version
```

These are the parameters you use to calculate the signature.

You also do not have a token_secret yet so the signing key is calculated using your consumer key appended with an ampersand ('&').

Comment: Right but the `oauth_signature` seems to require an `oauth_token` at least according to [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature)

Comment: That example refers to Authorized requests, i.e. requests you make to Twitter once you have obtained an access token. There are a few authentication requests where the oauth_token is not passed (such as obtaining an unauthorized request token) as stated on [this Twitter page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request)

Comment: Ok, still a tiny bit confused, can you just list all of the values I need to include in my authorization header for my request for an oauth_signature?